# How to Solve "Watchdog: nothing configured" Error in Ubuntu EC2 When Fetching Data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, watchdog

I have set up an Amazon EC2 instance using an Ubuntu image and installed Apache2 as the web server. My application relies on fetching data from Firebase Firestore. However, when I include the line $db = new Firestore(); in my code to instantiate the Firestore object, I encounter an error, and the data retrieval process fails. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue to successfully fetch data from Firebase Firestore in my Ubuntu EC2 environment?

My code is as below,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djySE.png) and my error is,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUd2c.png)

A solution for above issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to [include code, data and error messages as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16563198).